# Adding a Woocommerce Downloadable File From Custom Field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Using Advanced Custom Fields, I've added a *"Post Object"* field to my *Woocommerce* edit page, set to return Post IDs.

I'm trying to get data from these posts, and automatically populate my *Woocommerce* Downloadable Files from them.

The problem with my current code is that if I change the data in the custom field, and then save my product, it doesn't update the downloads. I need to update the product again for the downloads to be affected.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'mysite_add_downloads', 50, 1 );

function mysite_add_downloads( $product ){

        $mysite_select_albums = get_field('mysite_select_albums');

        $downloads = array(); // Clear $downloads variable

        foreach ($mysite_select_albums as $album) {

          // Gets Information About Download From Album Post Type
          $post = get_post($album);
          $file_title = $post->post_title;
          $file_url = "http://changingthinstosimplify.com/";
          $file_md5 = md5($file_url);

          $download  = new WC_Product_Download(); // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Download Object

          // Set the download data
          $download->set_name($file_title);
          $download->set_id($file_md5);
          $download->set_file($file_url);

          $downloads[$file_md5] = $download; // Insert the new download to the array of downloads
      }

      $product->set_downloads($downloads); // Set new array of downloads

}
```